# Escape special XML characters in Jinja2 with Ansible

Tags: xml, templates, variables, ansible, jinja2

I've got a couple strings I'm trying to substitute into an XML file via Ansible with Jinja. The problem is they have some special characters in them like `"` and `<`. To get around this, I'm currently doing this for all the fields in question:

```
<option name="mystring" value="{{ string_in_ansible | replace("&","&amp;") | replace("'","&apos;") | replace("\"","&quot;") | replace("<","&lt;") | replace(">","&gt;") }}"/>
```

This is a bit verbose and not at all dry when using with multiple variables. Is there anything built in for this kind of case, or a better way to express this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is [`escape`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#escape), although in your specific circumstance you may actually be happier with [`xmlattr`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#xmlattr)

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks!